# Minecraft won't work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On my Mac my Minecraft is broken. The "break" and "place" actions are being activated from the same button, although the settings say that "place" is button 2, aka right click, and button 1 is "break", aka left click, and I can't change it because it thinks left click and right click is the same button. How can I change this please?

Comment: Strings? settings

Comment: It may help to know what exact model of mouse you're using. Also, if at all possible, have you tried using a different mouse temporarily to see if it's a problem with the mouse that you normally use?

Comment: Is your mouse button settings on right/left click and not one click?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enabled right click/secondary click on your mac!

[Source](https://answers.uchicago.edu/page.php?id=28194)

> This article explains how to right click on a Mac computer running OS
>   X.
>
> These instructions were written for Mac OS X 10.7. In OS X, there are
>   several different ways to right-click, depending on what hardware you
>   have:
>
> If you have a MacBook (Pro and Air included), from 2008 or later, your trackpad can be enabled to right-click, either by tapping or
>   pressing a specific part of it, or by tapping or pressing with two
>   fingers. This option can be enabled in System Preferences, as follows:
>
> ```
>     Open System Preferences and then click Trackpad.
>     Make sure the box next to Secondary click is checked. Choose the way you would like to right-click from the drop-down menu below.
> ```
>
> OS X helpfully provides videos demonstrating each gesture, to allay
>   any possible confusion.
>       If you are using a computer with a mouse that has a right click button, you simply need to make sure your mouse preferences are set
>   properly. Even Apple's one button mice have been capable of
>   right-click functionality since 2005. To enable right-clicking, follow
>   these instructions:
>
> ```
>     Open System Preferences and then click Mouse.
>     A diagram of a mouse displays. Make sure the right-most button is set to "Secondary Button".
> ```
>
> Finally, there is a universal option, potentially useful if you are using older hardware:
>
> on any Mac, you can access right-click functionality by holding control and left-clicking (CTRL-click).